# Instruction ANDN in MASM throws EXCEPTION_ILLEGAL_INSTRUCTION

Tags: assembly, x86-64, masm

I am learning x86-64 assembly. Now, I am trying to use ANDN (AND NOT) instruction in MASM 64-bit (ML64.exe) to see in debugger how it works.

My code is:

```
extrn ExitProcess : proc
.data
.code
    Main proc
        mov ebx, 01h
        mov ecx, 01h
        andn eax, ebx, ecx ;EXCEPTION_ILLEGAL_INSTRUCTION here :(

        xor rcx, rcx
        call ExitProcess
    Main endp
end
```

I am using debugger x64dbg. On ANDN instruction it throws EXCEPTION_ILLEGAL_INSTRUCTION.

How to use this instruction correctly?

My build.bat file:

```
@echo off
ml64.exe prog1.asm /link /entry:Main /subsystem:windows /defaultlib:"kernel32.Lib"
pause
```

Regards, David

Comment: You probably need to use a CPU that supports the instruction.

Comment: Please go to the Control Panel and tell us what CPU you have. Only very new CPUs support the `andn` instruction. Alternatively, use `and` and then `not`.

Comment: If you want to check for this programmatically, I believe it's under `CPUID.(EAX=07H, ECX=0H):EBX.BMI1[bit 3]==1`.

Comment: I have Intel Core i3-3220 CPU 3.30 Ghz. Thank You all for comments. Now, I know that it's unsupported instruction. Before I didn't know what is happening.

Comment: Beware that `andn` is not a [NAND](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NAND_gate) ¬(*a* ∧ *b*), it is a ¬a ∧ *b*. Always check the "*CPUID feature flag*" column on the page of the instruction in the Intel SDM #2. If present it means that special ISA extensions are required.

Comment: Trivia - in the "olden" days (1960's, 1970's) on some processors, ANDN was named "selective clear": (¬a ∧ b) - for each bit set in `a`, the corresponding bit in `b` is cleared in the result, treating `a` as the `mask` operand and `b` as the `source` operand. The other "olden" days names for binary operators: "selective set" == OR, and "selective complement" == XOR.